# Counting the distance between values with python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am new to python and would be grateful for some help.

I have this script that counts every three bases in a sequence until it identifies a stop codon, then breaks and returns the value. This works for each reading frame 0, +1, +2.

I would like it to return a value of 0 it the script runs to the end of the sequence before identifying a stop codon. At the moment the script returns 18 for count0 which should be 0 as the sequence ends before finding either a "TAG" or a "TAA"

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

```
seq="TCATTCTaTTTAAAAAAatATAAAaGGGgTTTTGGGgTTTtGGGGTTTtGGGG"

stop_codons = ["TAG", "TAA"]
count0 = 0
n = 0
while n < len(seq):
    if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
        break
    count0 += 1
    n += 3
print count0      

count1 = 0
n = 1
while n < len(seq):
    if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
        break
    count1 += 1
    n += 3
print count1      

count2 = 0
n = 2
while n < len(seq):
    if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
        break
    count2 += 1
    n += 3
print count2
```

Result:

```
18
3
6
```

Comment: In your sample it finds TAA (I can see it too), so it prints 18. But you say it 'should be 0 as the sequence ends before finding either a "TAG" or a "TAA"'

Comment: Write a function taking n as parameter, please. You'll avoid a lot of code repetition and mistakes!

Comment: @doctorlove The TAA is in frame +1. that is starting from CATTCT... There is no stop in frame 0 TCATTCT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
seq="TCATTCTaTTTAAAAAAatATAAAaGGGgTTTTGGGgTTTtGGGGTTTtGGGG"
stop_codons = ["TAG", "TAA"]

def printcount(seq, stop_codons, start):
    found = False
    count = 0
    n = start
    while n < len(seq):
        if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
            found = True
            break        
        count += 1
        n += 3
    print count if found else 0

printcount(seq, stop_codons, 0)
printcount(seq, stop_codons, 1)
printcount(seq, stop_codons, 2)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my (or one of the others as most work) answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix would be to do something like this. Nevertheless you should consider refactor your code.

```
stop_codons = ["TAG", "TAA"]
count0 = 0
n = 0
found = False
while n < len(seq):
    if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
        found = True
        break
    count0 += 1
    n += 3

if not found:
    count0 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend pushing the iterating code into a function:

```
def get_codon_index(seq, start_idx):
    count = 0
    n = start_idx
    while n < len(seq):
        if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
            return count
        count += 1
        n += 3
    return -1
```

This way you save the effort of introducing boolean flags and avoid code duplication.

I return `-1` instead of `0`, because `0` might be an actual index of a codon (if the codon is right at the beginning of your sequence).

Answer (score 0):

You search for the stop codon, and if it finds it, it exits the loop prematurely.
But otherwise, it runs the complete loop, exits the loop when `n == len(seq)` and then still prints the count.

Two solutions:

Print only when you find a stop codon:

```
count1 = 0
n = 1
while n < len(seq):
    if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
        print count1
        break
    count1 += 1
    n += 3
```

or set a `stopped` flag:

```
count1 = 0
n = 1
stopped = False
while n < len(seq):
    if seq[n:n+3] in stop_codons:
        stopped = True
        break
    count1 += 1
    n += 3
if stopped:
    print count1
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will loop through your sequence and stops when it finds a TAA or TAG sequence returning the position of the first character of the stop codon

```
seq="TCATTCTaTTTAAAAAAatATAAAaGGGgTTTTGGGgTTTtGGGGTTTtGGGG"

list = ["z", "z", "z"] # otherwise the list will not be of 3 characters
i = 0

for letter in seq:
    list.pop(0)
    list.append(letter)
    codon = "".join(list)
    i = i + 1
    if codon == "TAG" or codon == "TAA":
        print i - 2 # to print the position of T
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and don't re-invent the wheel especially when [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) is freely available and widely used.